# Go composite literal for type of primitive value

Tags: go, integer, receiver, composite-literals

I am a new to Go and have a question. Maybe it is not a idiomatic Go code but just for studying purposes how to  make this code work? It seems that I can put as a receiver type of int, but how to call it in main?:

**xa.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"

type xa int

func (xl xa) print() {
    fmt.Println(xl)
}
```

**main.go**

```
package main

func main() {
    X := (xa{2})//not working
    X.print()
}
```

Run:

```
go run main.go xa.go
.\main.go:10:8: invalid composite literal type xa
```

Comment: consider this variation for further study. https://play.golang.org/p/nMRoqTgOue4

Comment: There is no composite literal for underlying type `int` because it's not a composite type. The curly brace syntax is for composite literals (structs, slices, arrays, and maps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
x := xa(2) // type conversion
x.print()
```

Or give a type to your variable, and you may use an [untyped constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to (a variable of type) `xa`:

```
var y xa = 3 // 3 is an untyped constant assignable to xa
y.print()
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2gzJhWOwLeF).